# How to send mails from a local webserver

Tags: wordpress, vagrant

I'm using vagrant which uses ubuntu to serve my Wordpress website. I simply want Wordpress to be able to send mails somehow. This is because I want to test email forms. Is there any way to do this? And how can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use a tool like [MailCatcher](https://mailcatcher.me/) and configure your wordpress installation to use its SMTP server — it comes with an email viewer —, or use a simple tool like `ssmtp` which will relay your requests to an actual mail server — like GMail.